# Why doesn't `IDictionary` allow you to easily get a value by key or default in its interface?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

While `Dictionary` allows you to get a value or `default(T)` via `GetValueOrDefault`, the corresponding `IDictionary` doesn't allow you to do the same and instead provides two cumbersome methods like:

- `operator[]` (which throws if the key doesn't exist)
- `TryGetValue` (which uses out parameters)

Coming from a C++ background I'm taught to think that if something that trivial is not provided it's probably because of a performance issue, but at the same time it's trivial to define an extension method using one of the two methods above:

```
public static class IDictionaryExtensions
{
    public static T GetValueOrDefault<K, T>(this IDictionary<K, T> dictionary, K key)
    {
        var value = default(T);
        bool hasValue = dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        if (hasValue) {
            return value;
        } else {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why this method is not provided? If not, is the above implementation equivalent to `Dictionary.GetValueOrDefault`?

Comment: Because interfaces should be minimal and, as you say, if it's needed you can write it yourself?

Comment: What you wrote looks almost exactly the same, except both `GetValueOrDefault()` and `TryGetValue()` call the private `FindEntry(TKey key)`, using a `comparer.GetHashCode(key)`, returning `default(T)` if not found. About the reason, already answered.

Comment: The short answer is because they didn't think of it when the interface was designed, and adding methods to public interfaces is a breaking change which has an extremely high bar for accepting the change.

Comment: It is for the universal reason, changing an interface starts at minus 1,000 points.  Minus 10,000,0000 points if it is an interface in the framework.  Which makes it impossible, it breaks entirely too much existing code.  Adding the GetValueOrDefault() convenience method to Dictionary two years ago was however not a problem, it didn't break much of anything.

Comment: Note that there is no Dictionary.GetValueOrDefault; it already is an extension method, but it's an extension on IReadOnlyDictionary. Why they chose to not create one for IDictionary is interesting and is outlined several corefx repo issues (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17917)). In summary, there were problems with ambiguity errors in common use cases so they decided not to include both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the people in .NET team can answer as to "why" a function is not provided.

As for your method, it looks fine but there are few redundant statements you can remove. It can be rewritten like this:

```
return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : default(T);
```

IMO this is redundant too because if `TryGetValue` returns `false`, *the value will be initialized to default* anyways. So whenever you need to use `GetValueOrDefault`, you can just use `TryGetValue`, inline `out` variable declarations makes it easy to use in a single line.